# Text that doesn't appear on the contribution page

Tags: contribution-page, paylater

For my contribution page: https://crm.teatronecessariogenova.org/civicrm/?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/contribute/transact&reset=1&id=1  - I checked the option: "Pay later"; in the editor I put the "Pay instructions later", but what I wrote in the editor doesn't appear on the "contribution" page. Thanks
[image]

Comment: Hi - thx for the screenshot. Are you using Multilingual - or just a translated version? Trying to understand what might be the special circumstances for your site that might be stopping this - also can you provide a link to the public facing form?

Comment: Of course, thanks petednz - fuzion, this is the link: https://crm.teatronecessariogenova.org/civicrm/?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/contribute/transact&reset=1&id=1  -  I'm using only the translated version, or rather ... it's an English version that I'm translating on the "word replacement" page

Comment: doing a test, I saw that only by going forward in the transaction, the form where I wrote the instructions to pay later appears! You need to fill in the fields and click CONFIRM CONTRIBUTION. The payment information on the Bank account is displayed on the next screen
Thanks to everyone anyway

Comment: Yep. I think the documentation is good but if you think it needs improvements you are welcome to make a suggestion or an edit. "Instructions added to Confirmation and Thank-you pages, as well as the confirmation email, when the user selects the 'pay later' option" - of course you don't need to use the Confirmation page if you don't want it (just in case you hadn't spotted that)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The text that you add to the "Pay Later Instructions' box should show per the following:

> Instructions added to Confirmation and Thank-you pages, as well as the confirmation email, when the user selects the 'pay later' option (e.g. 'Mail your check to ... within 3 business days.').

You said:

> what I wrote in the editor doesn't appear on the "contribution" page

Unsure if you incorrectly typed 'contribution' instead of 'confirmation', or if you meant what you typed, in which case the text is not expected to show.

The other text "Pay later label" should show on the Contribution page, but may only after an amount has been selected if (assuming more than one payment option is set up)

Please add any clarification you can to your original question via 'edit'

Comment: Screenshots are always good as well.

Comment: so I was right at the outset - the clue was that she referred to 'the "contribution" page'